# sometimes cannot access newly created files within synced folders

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox, virtualization

sometimes i got newly created files, which i can't access, although i can list them in console. my `Vagrant file` contains this synced_folder settings:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/home/ulkas/Develop/beauty/Beautyportal", "/vagrant/Beautyportal", owner: "vagrant", group: "vagrant", :mount_options => ['dmode=777', 'fmode=777']
```

it happens when i create/modify files in host as well as in guest, they just become unaccessible:

```
cannot access GuzzleStreamWrapper.php: No such file or directory
```

whats worth nothing is i can list them in console, but without permissions (looks like mounting issue):

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/Beautyportal/vendor/guzzlehttp/streams/src$ ls -al
ls: cannot access functions.php: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access NoSeekStream.php: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access LazyOpenStream.php: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access MetadataStreamInterface.php: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access StreamInterface.php: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access LimitStream.php: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access AppendStream.php: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Stream.php: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access CachingStream.php: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access StreamDecoratorTrait.php: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access GuzzleStreamWrapper.php: No such file or directory
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Aug 14 11:33 .
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Aug 14 11:33 ..
?????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? AppendStream.php
?????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? CachingStream.php
?????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? functions.php
?????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? GuzzleStreamWrapper.php
?????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? LazyOpenStream.php
?????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? LimitStream.php
?????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? MetadataStreamInterface.php
?????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? NoSeekStream.php
?????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? StreamDecoratorTrait.php
?????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? StreamInterface.php
?????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? Stream.php
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Aug 14 11:33 .svn
```

after i reboot the machine (`vagrant reload`), the files become accessible, thus i suspect there is something wrong with mounting/remounting.

this problems has appeared with linux mint 13 host as well as with windows 7 64bit host.
box is `hashicorp/precise64`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i have found the problem, it was due to duplicate mounting - be default, vagrant mounts the active host directory `/home/user/vagranthost` into `/vagrant`. what i have done is, i added additional subdirectory as a mount point like `/home/user/vagranthost/project` into `/vagrant/project` , thus creating a collision, which vagrant does not recognize (yet) and lets it mount.

thus, the solution to this was to edit the `Vagrantfile` and change the line

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/home/ulkas/Develop/beauty/Beautyportal", "/vagrant/Beautyportal", owner: "vagrant", group: "vagrant", :mount_options => ['dmode=777', 'fmode=777']
```

into

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/home/ulkas/Develop/beauty", "/vagrant", owner: "vagrant", group: "vagrant", :mount_options => ['dmode=775', 'fmode=775']
```

for debugging, this was in the output of `mount` command before:

```
/vagrant on /vagrant type vboxsf (uid=1000,gid=1000,rw)
/vagrant/Beautyportal on /vagrant/Beautyportal type vboxsf (uid=33,gid=1000,rw)
```